# Simplest form of $h'(y)$ given $h(y)= (1-3y^2)^5 \cdot ( y^2 + 2)^6$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $h'(y)$ in the simplest form if the $$h(y)= (1-3y^2)^5 \cdot ( y^2 + 2)^6$$

My answer was: $$-30y(1-3y^2)^4 \cdot (y^2+2)^6 + 12y(y^2+2)^5 \cdot (1-3y^2)^5$$

But according to wolfram alpha the answer was $$ -30y(1-3y^2)^4 \cdot (y^2+2)^6 $$ only. which makes it weird that they did not differentiate the second term my answer was different.

I posted it again because I did not get an answer.

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You differentiated correctly.

Since you have been asked to write the derivative in its *simplest form*:

you can factor out common factors in each term of your sum:

$$-30y(1-3y^2)^4 \cdot (y^2+2)^6 + 12y(y^2+2)^5(1-3y^2)^5$$ $$ = 6y(1-3y^2)^4(y^2 +2)^5\Big((-5)(y^2+2) + 2(1-3y^2)\Big)$$ $$ = 6y(1-3y^2)^4(y^2 +2)^5\Big(-5y^2-10 +2 -6y^2\Big) $$ $$=6y(1-3y^2)^4(y^2 +2)^5(-11y^2 - 8)$$

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes WolframAlpha writes things in strange forms. I find that the easiest way to get it to tell you the "normal" (for the purposes of Calc I) answer is to click the <kbd>Step-by-step solution</kbd> button (requires pro).
Your first answer is correct, however, after putting your derivative into WolframApha, I was unable to find anywhere that would seem to imply that the final answer is $-30y(1-3y^2)^4 \cdot (y^2+2)^6$. The most similar answer to that, that I saw, was $-6 y (y^2+2)^5 (3 y^2-1)^4 (11 y^2+8)$.
[image]

Comment: or just input "expected answer" - "wolfram answer".. if it is $0$ you're good :P

Comment: Wow, thaanks I did not know that!

Comment: Why thumps down!